# Why does my headset swallow the notification sounds?

Tags: notifications, bluetooth, audio, headset

I've used the Blueparrott B250-XT+ headset for many years now. I love this headset, and I found it after trying a bunch of other models. I have 4 of these now.

(My phone is a OnePlus 5T, OxygenOS version 9.0.5, Android version 9.)

I've been using it happily for years, but now there's a new problem when using it. All notification sounds, such as ringing in case I get a call, or message notifications, are being heard on the headset instead of on the phone's speaker.

I discovered this after a few days of frustration where I would miss phone calls and messages. I thought I was maybe on "Do not disturb" mode, but I wasn't. After some trial-and-error, I discovered that I don't hear the notifications only when the headset is connected, and that the notification is being heard in the headset, which isn't usually on my head.

In the Bluetooth configuration, the headset has "Phone calls" on but "Media audio" off.

**Why is this happening and how do I fix it?** I'm afraid to connect my headset right now because I don't want to miss calls and messages.

Comment: For me it is normal behavior. If Bluetooth hands-free profile is connected, ringing sounds and message notifications are heard in the headset, not from phone speaker. Similar to wired headsed. Not sure how the phone should behave in case when only hands-free SLC (control) connection is established, but if in-band ringing is supported, it should establish SCO (audio) connection on incoming ring anyway.

Comment: BTW do you have something like “Enable in-band ringing” or “Disable in-band ringing.” in the Developer Options? If such option is present, changing it can help.

Comment: @hank15 I looked for that now and didn't find it. Good thinking though.

Comment: Have no familiar OnePlus to check. Maybe they moved this option into Feature Flags?

Comment: @hank15 I checked the Feature Flags now, nothing useful there.